# Context menu on QGraphicsItemGroup qt

Tags: qt, contextmenu

I try to have a context menu in Qt if we do a long press on a QGraphicsItemGroup. First I have try basic thing like this:
my .h:

```
class myclass: public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    myclass(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~myclass();

public slots:
    void contextMenuEvent(QGraphicsSceneContextMenuEvent *event);

private:
    Ui::myclassClass ui;
```

my cpp:

```
void myclass::contextMenuEvent(QGraphicsSceneContextMenuEvent *event)
{
    if (event->GraphicsSceneMouseDoubleClick)
    {
        qDebug() << "Test";
    }
}
```

but just this simple thing doesn't work. What is wrong with my code ?

Comment: Do you forget `Q_OBJECT` macro?

Comment: `don't work` - what do you mean?

Comment: @Glutton i have edit with the top of .h
by don't work i want mean nothing appen

Comment: Do you use C++11? If yes, try to add `override` keyword after `contextMenuEvent` declaration. I'm not sure that `QGraphicsSceneContextMenuEvent` derived from `QContextMenuEvent`. If I'm right you will get compile time error.

Comment: @Gluttton Like contextMenuEvent::override ?

Comment: No, `void contextMenuEvent(QGraphicsSceneContextMenuEvent *event) override;` But only if you use C++11!

Comment: @Gluttton How to know if i use c++11 ?

Comment: if you don't know when you are not using it. OK, go ahead... I believe that your `contextMenuEvent` doesn't overload `QMainWidget::contextMenuEvent` because it has different signature. You need use [`void contextMenuEvent(QContextMenuEvent *event);`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmainwindow.html#contextMenuEvent) instead of `void contextMenuEvent(QGraphicsSceneContextMenuEvent *event);`

Comment: @Gluttton thanks, it's work. But now how to put it for a long left click and on a QGraphicsItemGroup ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current declaration of `contextMenuEvent` doesn't override corresponding method of `QMainWindow` because it has different [signature](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmainwindow.html#contextMenuEvent).

So you need replace:

```
void contextMenuEvent(QGraphicsSceneContextMenuEvent *event);
```

on:

```
void contextMenuEvent(QContextMenuEvent *event);
```

Note: C++11 allow find this problem at compile time with help of `override` keyword:

```
void contextMenuEvent(QContextMenuEvent *event) override;
```

Comment: thanks, it's work. But now how to put it for a long left click and on a QGraphicsItemGroup ?